# read an excel sheet with xlrd and find a cell value below the string you search for

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I am new, so excuse my ignorance if I ask something wrong please. I need to search a workbook to find a string, then I need to get my cell value from the cell directly below that string. When I have found the value, I want to take it and change the filename of the .xls to retain the first three letters of the filename and append the found value on to it. It could be anywhere in the sheet, there are no headers, it is more like a form. Any help is appreciated, I can't seem to find an answer to this. What I have tried is below for finding the cell value of the string I searched for. I just can't pull the data in the cell below. I have thousands of these files to look through and 2 possible strings, although I have not gotten that far along in my python code yet:

```
import os
from xlrd import open_workbook
path = "a_path"

for filename in os.listdir(path):


    book = open_workbook("some_workbook")


for sheet in book.sheets():
for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
    row = sheet.row(rowidx)
    for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):

        if cell.value == "String" :
                 print (sheet.name)
                 print (colidx)
                 print (rowidx)
                 print (cell.value)
```

New code. I am further along, but I cannot find a way to limit the columns now that I have gotten to the next row.

```
import os
import re
import xlrd
def rename_excel_files():
path = filename

for filename in os.listdir(path):   
    try:    
        book = xlrd.open_workbook(path + filename)
    except:
        pass
    try:
        sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
        for rowidx in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowidx)
            for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                m = re.search(r' string ', str(cell.value))
                if m: 
                    nextrow = sheet.row(rowidx + 1)
                    for i, cell2 in enumerate(nextrow):
                        newfileERnbr = (str(cell2.value).split('.')[0])
                        print (filename + newfileERnbr)
    except:
        pass                   
rename_excel_files()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me. It is not perfect, but it worked really well. Hopefully, it might help someone else in the future. Thanks.

Code:

```
import os
import re
import xlrd
def rename_excel_files():
    my_list = [list] # list is your list of locations
    for path in my_list:
        for filename in os.listdir(path):   
            try:    
                book = xlrd.open_workbook(path + filename)
            except:
                pass
            try:
                sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0) #sheet number 0 based
                for rowidx in range(0,50): #row range
                    row = sheet.row(rowidx)
                    for colidx, cell in enumerate(row):
                        m = re.search(research string, str(cell.value)) #research string is you regex that you are looking for, re paramaters will change for need below
                        q = re.search(research string, str(cell.value)) #research string is you regex that you are looking for
                        if m:
                            celllocation = sheet.cell(rowidx + 1 , colidx)
                            p = (str(celllocation).split('.')[0])
                            n = re.search('\d+', p)                        
#  test                         print (path + filename + '---------->', path + filename[0:3] + '_' + n.group() + ".xls")
                            if os.path.isfile(path + filename[0:3] + '_' + n.group() + ".xls"):
                                print ("File Exists Already " + path + filename)
                            else:
                                print (path + filename + '---------->', path + filename[0:3] + '_' + n.group() + ".xls")
                                os.rename (path + filename, path + filename[0:3] + '_' + n.group() + ".xls")
                        elif q:
                            celllocation = sheet.cell(rowidx + 1 , colidx)
                            p = (str(celllocation).split('.')[0])
                            n = re.search('\d+', p)
#    test                       print (path + filename + '---------->', path + filename[0:3] + '_' + n.group() + ".xls")
                            if os.path.isfile(path + filename[0:3] + '_' + n.group() + ".xls"):
                                print ("File Exists Already " + path + filename)
                            else:
                                print (path + filename + '---------->', path + filename[0:3] + '_' + n.group() + ".xls")
                                os.rename (path + filename, path + filename[0:3] + '_' + n.group() + ".xls")
                sheet.unload () #speeds the whole thing up because you are closing the sheet and moving on to the next one
            except:
                pass                   
rename_excel_files()
```